# How do I unload multiple userforms in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have quite a few userforms in an excel workbook.
 As the user moves between the forms, they are hidden.
 What code can I use to unload all the userforms in one shot?

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Unload UserForm15
Unload UserForm14
Unload UserForm13 
Unload UserForm12
Unload UserForm11
Unload UserForm10
Unload UserForm9 
Unload UserForm8
Unload UserForm7
Unload UserForm6
Unload UserForm5
Unload UserForm4
Unload userform3
Unload UserForm2
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Is there a shorter code to do this, or have I answered my own question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms can be cycled through like other objects

```
Sub testIt2()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = VBA.UserForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Unload VBA.UserForms(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Not tested

Comment: Answer taken from here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/69426-unload-all-userforms.html All the documentation they link to appears to 404, hopefully you can use this.